# How to create tri-state Switch button?

Tags: ios, swift, togglebutton

please help me, i've been looking many site and can't even find any way to create tri-state switch button, the default switch button in storyboard is just two-state.
the UI should be like this

[image]

Comment: what is the situation where you need 3 states?

Comment: the left for yes, and right for no and the center is to initial it which mean it hasn't pressed yet @Martheli

Comment: are you going to end up with just 1 button or do you need multiple?

Comment: one button only, just see the picture which i added

Comment: the reason I ask is because you can get the same effect multiple ways without having to design a new type of button.

Comment: You could create a custom `UIControl`. Here's an Apple tutorial. https://developer.apple.com/library/content/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/DevelopiOSAppsSwift/ImplementingACustomControl.html

Comment: Have you tried a UISegmentedControl? I think it will fit for you: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uisegmentedcontrol

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to create a new type of button. If all you want to do is keep track of if the button was tapped or not you can first define a bool to keep track of the state:

```
var isTouched = false
```

Then you can create a value changed action from the UISwitch that changes the value to true when it's been changed:

```
 @IBAction func isTapped(_ sender: Any) {
        isTouched = true

    }
```

Now you can always check the value of isTouched to see if the switch has been touched and you can get the value of the button itself by:

```
let value = testSwitch.isOn
```